# How to Calculate time in Seconds From multiple Dates?

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some dates in list collection as given below

```
new List<EventItemModel>()
{
 new EventItemModel() {DateTime = new DateTime(2017,1,1,10,0,0), Event = EventType.Enter},
 new EventItemModel() {DateTime = new DateTime(2017,1,1,10,30,0), Event = EventType.Pass},
 new EventItemModel() {DateTime = new DateTime(2017,1,1,11,30,0), Event = EventType.Leave},
}
```

from sing this function i am calculating time in seconds from a date collection

```
 public static double GetTotalDurationFor(this Enumerable<EventItemModel> lst)
    {
        var selectedEmployeDayinout = lst.OrderBy(d => d.DateTime).ToList();
        const int enterExitOperations = 1;
        double duration = 0;

        if ((selectedEmployeDayinout.Count() % enterExitOperations) == 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedEmployeDayinout.Count(); i++)
            {
                var enterDate = selectedEmployeDayinout[i].DateTime;
                var leaveDate = selectedEmployeDayinout[i + 1].DateTime;
                duration += leaveDate.Subtract(enterDate).TotalMinutes;
            }
            return duration;
        }
        return duration;
    }
```

but when i sent collection to this function  this gives errors:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: **errors in loop **

Comment: @SavitaVerma: What it says?

Comment: actually i am calculating time from a collection through loop

10:00 - 10:30 = 30 Minutes
10:30 - 11:30 = 60 Minutes 

** Total Calculated time is 90 Minutes  **

Comment: @SavitaVerma : fine, whats wrong with that? whats the error message that you are getting?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @SavitaVerma this line of code probably causes OutOfRangeException var leaveDate = selectedEmployeDayinout[i + 1].DateTime; When loop gets to the last iteration, you are trying to access [i+1] index which is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies on this line

```
 for (var i = 0; i < selectedEmployeDayinout.Count(); i++)
```

You loop from `0` to `selectedEmployeDayinout.Count()` **minus one**. And then inside the loop

```
var leaveDate = selectedEmployeDayinout[i + 1].DateTime;
```

That's error because for the last iteration you access `selectedEmployeDayinout` at index `selectedEmployeDayinout.Count()` (that value **minus one** at last iteration and then **plus one**).

You should change `for (var i = 0; i < selectedEmployeDayinout.Count(); i++)` to `for (var i = 0; i < selectedEmployeDayinout.Count()-1; i++)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use TimeSpan class to calculate Time difference in c#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He does.  Note the `Subtract` call, which returns a `TimeSpan` instance.